# using toggle by getting dynamic id from ng-repeat from scope

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

Hi i am making a UI that consist of links if clicked they should pop up another data using toggle but i am getting this data from ng-repeat so if i am clicking on one ;ink all data is shown can you please tell em how to call toggle method so at each link click only that particular data should pop up.
my code for html is

```html
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
  <head>
    <title>UI</title>
    <script src="jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="angular.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jquery-ui.css"/>
    <script src="jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"/>
  </head>
  <body style="background-color:#F2F2F2" ng-controller="maincontroller">
    <div class="first">
      <div class="container">
        <table>
          <tr>
          </tr>
        </table>
        
        <table>
          <tbody>
          <tr>
            <div class="get">
              <h4>Station</h4>
              <p>HKG</p><h4>Airline Operator</h4>
              <p>Y7</p><h4>Aircraft Model</h4>
              <p>A300-600F</p><h4>Configuration Class</h4>
              <p>Cargo</p><h4>Service Type</h4>
              <p>Transit</p>
            </div>
            <th id="cool"><img src="pic4.png" height="30px" width="30px" padding-top="30px">TTS142</th>
            <td ng-repeat="do in info" ng-style="{'backgroundColor':do.color1,'width':do.number}" class="fool">
              <a href="#" class="link">{{do.name}}</a>
              <div class="tooltip">{{do.tooltip}}</div>
            </td>
            <th id="cool"><img src="pic3.png" height="30px" width="30px" padding-top="30px">TTS142</th>
          </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
        
        <table>
          <tr>
            <div class="get">
              <h4>Station</h4>
              <p>HKG</p><h4>Airline Operator</h4>
              <p>Y7</p><h4>Aircraft Model</h4>
              <p>A300-600F</p><h4>Configuration Class</h4>
              <p>Cargo</p><h4>Service Type</h4>
              <p>Transit</p>
            </div>
            <th id="cool"><img src="pic4.png" height="30px" width="30px" padding-top="50px">TTS143</th>
            <td ng-repeat="do in info1" ng-style="{'backgroundColor':do.color1,'width':do.number}">
              <a href="#" class="link">{{do.name}}</a>
              <div class="tooltip"></div>
            </td>
            <th id="cool"><img src="pic3.png" height="30px" width="30px" padding-top="50px">TTS143</th>
          </tr>
        </table>
        
        <table>
          <tr>
            <div class="get">
              <h4>Station</h4>
              <p>HKG</p><h4>Airline Operator</h4>
              <p>Y7</p><h4>Aircraft Model</h4>
              <p>A300-600F</p><h4>Configuration Class</h4>
              <p>Cargo</p><h4>Service Type</h4>
              <p>Transit</p>
            </div>
            <th id="cool"><img src="pic4.png" height="30px" width="30px" padding-top="50px">TTS163</th>
            <td ng-repeat="do in info2" ng-style="{'backgroundColor':do.color1,'width':do.number}">
              <a href="#" class="link">{{do.name}}</a>
              <div class="tooltip">this file is on schedule</div>
            </td>
            <th id="cool"><img src="pic3.png" height="30px" width="30px" padding-top="50px">TTS163</th>
          </tr>
        </table>
        
        <table>
          <tr>
            <div class="get">
              <h4>Station</h4>
              <p>HKG</p><h4>Airline Operator</h4>
              <p>Y7</p><h4>Aircraft Model</h4>
              <p>A300-600F</p><h4>Configuration Class</h4>
              <p>Cargo</p><h4>Service Type</h4>
              <p>Transit</p>
            </div>
            <th id="cool"><img src="pic4.png" height="30px" width="30px" padding-top="50px">TTS182</th>
            <td ng-repeat="do in info3" ng-style="{'backgroundColor':do.color1,'width':do.number}">
              <a href="#" class="link">{{do.name}}</a>
              <div class="tooltip">this file is on schedule</div>
            </td>
            <th id="cool"><img src="pic3.png" height="30px" width="30px" padding-top="50px">TTS182</th>
          </tr>
        </table>
        
        <div>
          <ul class="legend">
            <li><span class="arrival"></span>Arrival</li>
            <li><span class="Groundhandling"></span>Ground handling</li>
            <li><span class="Departure"></span> Departure</li>
          </ul>
          <div>
            <a href="#" class="link1">legend codes</a>
            <div class="tooltip1">
              <table>
                <tr>AOB - Aircraft on block</tr>
                <br>
                <tr>CC - Cabin cleaning</tr>
                <br>
                <tr>MB - Maintenance Block</tr>
                <br>
                <tr>TS - Toilet Servicing</tr>
                <br>
                <tr>WS - Water Servicing</tr>
                <br>
                <tr>R - Refulleing</tr>
                <br>
                <tr>PB - Push back</tr>
                <br>
                <tr>LT - Long Towing-Arrival to Parking</tr>
              </table>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="second">
      <div class="container">
        <table style="width:100%">
          <tr>
            <div class="get">
              <h4>Station</h4>
              <p>HKG</p><h4>Airline Operator</h4>
              <p>Y7</p><h4>Aircraft Model</h4>
              <p>A300-600F</p><h4>Configuration Class</h4>
              <p>Cargo</p><h4>Service Type</h4>
              <p>Transit</p>
            </div>
            <th id="cool"><img src="pic4.png" height="50px" width="50px" padding-top="50px">TTS185</th>
            <td ng-repeat="do in info1" ng-style="{'backgroundColor':do.color1,'width':do.number}">
              <a href="#" class="link">{{do.name}}</a>
              <div class="tooltip">this file is on schedule</div>
            </td>
            <th id="cool"><img src="pic3.png" height="50px" width="50px" padding-top="50px">TTS185</th>
          </tr>
        </table>
        
        <div>
          <ul class="legend">
            <li><span class="arrival"></span>Arrival</li>
            <li><span class="Groundhandling"></span>Ground handling</li>
            <li><span class="Departure"></span> Departure</li>
          </ul>
          <div>
            <a href="#" class="link1">legend codes</a>
            <div class="tooltip1">
              <table>
                <tr>AOB - Aircraft on block</tr>
                <br>
                <tr>CC - Cabin cleaning</tr>
                <br>
                <tr>MB - Maintenance Block</tr>
                <br>
                <tr>TS - Toilet Servicing</tr>
                <br>
                <tr>WS - Water Servicing</tr>
                <br>
                <tr>R - Refulleing</tr>
                <br>
                <tr>PB - Push back</tr>
                <br>
                <tr>LT - Long Towing-Arrival to Parking</tr>
              </table>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="click1">
        <a href="#"><img src="pic7.png" width="30px" height="25px"></a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="click"><a href="#"><img src="pic6.png" width="30px" height="25px"></a></div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

and this is my angular code

```js
var App = angular.module("myApp", []);
App.controller("maincontroller", function ($scope) {
  $scope.info = [
    {
      name: 'aob',
      number: '10%',
      color1: '#FF3300',
      tooltip: 'sbsjasjahsj'
    },
    {
      name: 'cc',
      number: '20%',
      color1: '#FF3300',
      tooltip: 'sbsjasjahsj'
    },
    {
      name: 'mb',
      number: '5%',
      color1: '#00FFFF',
      tooltip: 'sbsjasjahsj'
    },
    {
      name: 'ts',
      number: '20%',
      color1: '#00FFFF',
      tooltip: 'sbsjasjahsj'
    },
    {
      name: 'ws',
      number: '8%',
      color1: '#00FFFF',
      tooltip: 'sbsjasjahsj'
    },
    {
      name: 't',
      number: '2%',
      color1: '#00FFFF',
      tooltip: 'sbsjasjahsj'
    },
    {
      name: 'aob',
      number: '15%',
      color1: '#66FF66',
      tooltip: 'sbsjasjahsj'
    },
    {
      name: 'pb',
      number: '2%',
      color1: '#66FF66',
      tooltip: 'sbsjasjahsj'
    }
  ];

  $scope.info1 = [
    {
      name: 'aob',
      number: '10%',
      color1: '#FF3300'
    },
    {
      name: 'cc',
      number: '20%',
      color1: '#FF3300'
    },
    {
      name: 'mb',
      number: '5%',
      color1: '#00FFFF'
    },
    {
      name: 'ts',
      number: '20%',
      color1: '#00FFFF'
    },
    {
      name: 'ws',
      number: '8%',
      color1: '#00FFFF'
    },
    {
      name: 't',
      number: '2%',
      color1: '#00FFFF'
    },
    {
      name: 'aob',
      number: '15%',
      color1: '#66FF66'
    },
    {
      name: 'pb',
      number: '2%',
      color1: '#66FF66'
    },
    {
      name: 'ws',
      number: '8%',
      color1: '#66FF66'
    }
  ];

  $scope.info2 = [
    {
      name: 'aob',
      number: '10%',
      color1: '#FF3300'
    },
    {
      name: 'ws',
      number: '8%',
      color1: '#ff3300'
    },
    {
      name: 'cc',
      number: '20%',
      color1: '#FF3300'
    },
    {
      name: 'mb',
      number: '5%',
      color1: '#00FFFF'
    },
    {
      name: 'ts',
      number: '20%',
      color1: '#00FFFF'
    },
    {
      name: 'ws',
      number: '8%',
      color1: '#00FFFF'
    },
    {
      name: 't',
      number: '2%',
      color1: '#00FFFF'
    },
    {
      name: 'aob',
      number: '15%',
      color1: '#66FF66'
    },
    {
      name: 'pb',
      number: '2%',
      color1: '#66FF66'
    },
    {
      name: 'ws',
      number: '8%',
      color1: '#66FF66'
    }
  ];

  $scope.info3 = [
    {
      name: 'aob',
      number: '10%',
      color1: '#FF3300'
    },
    {
      name: 'cc',
      number: '20%',
      color1: '#FF3300'
    },
    {
      name: 'mb',
      number: '5%',
      color1: '#ff3300'
    },
    {
      name: 'ws',
      number: '8%',
      color1: '#00FFFF'
    },
    {
      name: 'ts',
      number: '20%',
      color1: '#00FFFF'
    },
    {
      name: 'ws',
      number: '8%',
      color1: '#00FFFF'
    },
    {
      name: 't',
      number: '2%',
      color1: '#00FFFF'
    },
    {
      name: 'aob',
      number: '15%',
      color1: '#66FF66'
    },
    {
      name: 'pb',
      number: '2%',
      color1: '#66FF66'
    },
    {
      name: 'ws',
      number: '8%',
      color1: '#66FF66'
    }
  ]
});
```

and my jquery code

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#click').click(function(){
 $('.first').hide();
 $('.second').show();

});
$('#click1').click(function(){
 $('.first').show();
 $('.second').hide();

});


$('.link1').click(function(){
 $(".tooltip1").toggle("slow");
});
$('.link').click(function(){
 $(".tooltip").toggle("slow");
});


 });
```

and at last my css

```css
.second {
  display: none;
}
#click {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
}
#click1 {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}
#good {
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  display: inline;
  padding-top: 100px;

}
body {
 /**/
}
h4 {
  display: inline;
}
p {
  display: inline;
}
#cool {
  font-size: 10px;
  width: 50px;
  padding-top: 20px;
}
table {
  padding-top: 20px;
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 1000px;
  height: 75px;
}
#hello {
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
}
#hello td {
  width: 50px;
}
td {
  padding-top: 25px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  overflow: hidden;

}
.process {
  display: none;
}
.tooltip {
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  padding: 30px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  background-color: #F2F2F2;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  box-shadow: 0 0 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
  border-radius: 3px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.tooltip1 {
  width: 600px;
  height: 200px;
  padding: 30px;
  top: 0px;
  background-color: #D3D3D3;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  box-shadow: 0 0 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
  border-radius: 3px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
  position: absolute;
  top:;
  left:;
  display: none;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.tooltip1 {
  z-index: 100;
}
.tooltip {
  z-index: 100;
}
.link {
  display: block;
  width: auto;
  position: relative;
}
.link1 {
  display: block;
  width: auto;
  position: center;
}
#jog {
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
}
.get {
  padding-left: 40px;
}
.get h4 {
  font-size: 12px;
  padding-left: 50px;
}
.get p {
  font-size: 13px;
  padding-left: 10px;
}
/* basic positioning */
.legend {
  list-style: none;
  padding-left: 150px;
}
.legend li {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 150px;
}
.legend span {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  float: left;
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  margin: 2px;
}
/* your colors */
.legend .arrival {
  background-color: #FF3300;
}
.legend .Groundhandling {
  background-color: #00FFFF;
}
.legend .Departure {
  background-color: #66FF66;
}
```

Comment: can you also put the same code on [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/) or [JS fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/fyMLb39mYBc9kOg4PK4k?p=preview

Comment: See my comment below the answer of @vijayp.

Answer (score 0):

As you are dealing with `class`; you will face the above problem because all the links and `div` has classes as `link1`, `link`, `tooltip1` and `tooltip`.

To avoid it; you will have to target associated `tooltip` div as follows:
I have come up with following code by looking at your HTML:

```
$('.link1').click(function(){
    $(this).closest("div").find(".tooltip1").toggle("slow");
});

$('.link').click(function(){
    $(this).closest("td").find(".tooltip").toggle("slow");
});
```

Comment: thanks i,l try i put my all codes in plunker if u want to have a look
http://plnkr.co/edit/fyMLb39mYBc9kOg4PK4k?p=preview

Comment: You are using AngularJS already. Why do you make use of jQuery then? It's a total overkill to use Angular for the `ng-repeat` only. Angular also offers the concept of `directives` which attach a specified behavior to a DOM element (e.g. via event listeners). Think in components and use directives for DOM manipulations and event listeners such as `click`. So your directive would register an `click` event on a single element which can then be toggled.

Comment: @deepakarya - if you want to use jQuery then you can take a look at http://plnkr.co/edit/fFoqQwALcICriuyoVf4y?p=preview. Its working as per your requirement.

Comment: Glad to know it @deepakarya... `:)`!